# C two-dimensional array of two-dimensional array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I want to represent a sudoku board as a 2-dim array of 2-dim array. The inner array contains 3 rows x 3 columns, making up a box of 9 cells. The outer array should also be 3x3 holding the 9 boxes.

How should I write this structure in C? 
int board[[3]][[3]]? Of course it is wrong.
Is it actually do-able in C?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In C, you can make a 4 dimensional array, with an outer and inner set of coordinates.

```
int board[3][3][3][3];
```

Or you can make a struct to represent the inner board;

```
struct InnerBoard {
  int board[3][3];
};

InnerBoard board[3][3];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think a struct will definitely make the program clearer.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a 4-dimensional array.

```
int board[3][3][3][3];
```

The first two indices determine which box, and the second two indices determine which cell inside of the box.